# What graphical methods are useful for visualising how uncertainties aggregate?

Tags: data-visualization, confidence-interval, uncertainty

I have a set of systems where uncertainties accumulate within it. These aren't always purely additive - sometimes they are, sometimes they aren't. I've had some success in using fan-charts, bar charts with confidence-intervals, and box plots for communicating single items.

But how can I show how uncertainties accumulate and combine - while also showing the data points around which the uncertainties lie?

Comment: You might want to make your question more specific.

Comment: Try [alluvial diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alluvial_diagram), flow glyphs, animation or audio-visual solutions.

Comment: Including example data that answerers can attempt to create appropriate diagrams for, would be very helpful. Even if it's just "toy data".

Answer (score 1):

Apperently http://www.getguesstimate.com/ is what you are searching for.

They are offering spreadsheets for prediction that aggregate the uncertainty in each prediction. They also include some visualisations.

A nice example could be found here: http://www.getguesstimate.com/models/314

> **What can Guesstimate be used for?**
>
> Guesstimate is great at making estimates of things that aren't certain. You can forecast your earnings from a new venture, predict the amount of time a big project will take, or experiment with scientific theories. People have used it to optimize video games, understand lottery payoffs, and estimate the costs of their childcare.